# OpenNMS Connection and Networking

Tags: opennms

I installed OpenNMS latest release on WIndows8.1, but i can not go to topology page becouse it is not presente, how can i fixed this problem?
And Is possible run OpenNMS without internet connection?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have this problem with latest version of OpenNMS Horizon 17.1.1? There are two pages, one is the topology view and the other one is the geographical map. The geographical map can be configured to use OpenStreetMap, Google Maps or MapQuest. If you want to run it without Internet connection you probably need to provide a local tile server for example in OpenStreetMap.